# Auto Layout Determine The Size of a Subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have a `KSSection` `UIView` subclass that I'm trying to use to do collapsing / expanding of different sections. It has a child view (set by an `IBOutlet`) called `content`. The `content`'s size is determined by a number of child views (`UILabel`, `UIImageView`, etc.) that are all variable size.

Currently I'm pinning the leading and trailing space of the `content` to the parent `KSSection`, aligning it centred vertically, and adding a `remove at runtime` constraint that the heights of `content` and `section` are equal. If I disable the `remove at runtime` everything works great - except that I can't collapse the view.

How can I calculate the size of the `content` to be used as the `intrinsicContentSize` of the `KSection`? So far I have the following snippet, but the call to `intrinsicContentSize` always returns `UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric` for both properties.

```
@implementation SKContainer

- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize
{
    if (self.collapsed) return CGSizeZero;
    else return [self.content intrinsicContentSize];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
}

- (void)setCollapsed:(BOOL)collapsed
{
    if (_collapsed != collapsed)
    {
        _collapsed = collapsed;

        [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
    }
}

@end
```

**Edit:**

Sorry to clarify it is actually returning `UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric` for both dimensions of the `CGSize`.

Attaching a sample: http://cl.ly/2F3s3X3y2U1H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so my previous answer was on an unnecessary track. What I ended up doing was this:

First, I removed the section view entirely, leaving us with just the plain vanilla content view to play the role of the section. (The section view was just adding an extra layer of complication.) Then I *lowered the priority* of the section view height to 250, and ran the project. Presto! The section view now expands, all by itself, driven by the constraints of the labels within it.

Second, here's how I collapse and expand. I keep an outlet to two of the constraints: the section height constraint, and the last constraint in the height stack of the internal constraints. Then my expand/collapse code looks like this:

```
- (IBAction)toggleButtonSelector:(id)sender
{
    self.collapsed = !self.collapsed;
    if (self.collapsed) {
        self.sectionHeightConstraint.constant = 10; // or whatever height you like
        self.sectionHeightConstraint.priority = 999;
        [NSLayoutConstraint deactivateConstraints:@[self.bottomInternalConstraint]];
    } else {
        self.sectionHeightConstraint.priority = 250;
        [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[self.bottomInternalConstraint]];

    }
}
```

You see, we need to overcome the desire of the internal stack of constraints to keep us expanded, so we remove one of the constraints in order to collapse, and we set the height constraint to a small number and raise its priority. To expand, we reverse that: we restore the missing internal constraint, and lower the priority of the overall section height constraint once again.

**EDIT** A really cool byproduct of this implementation is that we can now animate the collapse/expand effect merely by appending these lines of code at the end of that method:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
```

Comment: It looks really cool with the animation. Notice that I had to set your view's `clipsToBounds` to YES; otherwise we still see all the subviews even after everything else has moved!

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing `-intrinsicContentSize`, both in why you're calling it and in your attempt to implement it for your view class. That method is for returning a size which is "intrinsic" to its nature and contents. It can not depend on other views, other constraints, etc. It also has nothing to do with the view's *current* size, because a view can be compressed or stretched from its intrinsic size by other constraints.

You should use constraints to make your view depend on its collapsed state and its subview's size (resulting from other constraints in combination with descendant views' intrinsic sizes, if they have any).

For example, assuming you want your view to collapse in the vertical direction, you might have constraints which always pin the content subview to the top, leading, and trailing edges. If your view is collapsed, you would have a constraint to make its height zero. You would **not** constrain your view's bottom to the content view's bottom. The content view would have its normal height, but that would all be clipped out by virtue of the fact that its superview has zero height.

On the other hand, if your view is not collapsed, you would remove the height constraint on your view and add a constraint connecting your view's bottom to the content view's bottom.

Comment: "On the other hand, if your view is not collapsed, you would remove the height constraint on your view and add a constraint connecting your view's bottom to the content view's bottom" Great minds think alike. That's exactly what I ended up doing, completely independently (I didn't see your answer until I had finished) - except you have to have _some_ height constraint on the view so I used a low-priority constraint. Beats me how you envisioned this; I had to play around with it to grasp what was going on. I guess I can't think in 2D!

Comment: You only need a height constraint on the view if the content view (its subview) doesn't have a height as a consequence of its internal constraints. For example, in a really simple case, if the content view is a label, it will have a height (intrinsic, in this case). The fact that the container view has its top pinned to the content view's top and its bottom pinned to the content view's bottom gives it a height without any explicit height constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Using solutions from @ken and @matt my final code (still using the SKContainer) is:

```
@interface SKContainer ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *expandedLayoutConstraint;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *collapsedLayoutConstraint;

@end

@implementation SKContainer

- (void)setCollapsed:(BOOL)collapsed
{
    if (_collapsed != collapsed)
    {
        _collapsed = collapsed;

        [self removeConstraint:collapsed ? self.expandedLayoutConstraint : self.collapsedLayoutConstraint];
        [self addConstraint:collapsed ? self.collapsedLayoutConstraint : self.expandedLayoutConstraint];
    }
}

@end
```

Where `expandedLayoutConstraint` is a equal height constraint to the `content` view and `collapsedLayoutConstraint` is a height `0` priority `200` constraint.

Comment: Thanks for posting back. Yes, I wasn't trying to hand you a definitive solution, just getting things started down a different road. Glad you found a way of your own in the end.